# QGIS multiplying one column of attribute table with another

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have population data for european countries, and a random rate attached to that population data. Is there a way to multiply my population data with that rate within the attribute table?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first need to replace the commas in your "Rate" field with a decimal point and then convert this to a real number so that it could be used numerically. Try something like the following:

```
"Population" * to_real(replace( "Rate" , ',', '.' ))
```